# {% block %} in {% blocktrans %}

Tags: django, django-templates

I am planning to implement Arabic translation that translates it making a whole sentence to be written right-to-left. How should I do this?:

```
<!-- parent.html -->
{% blocktrans %}
    {% block category %}{% endblock category %} - Site Name
{% endblocktrans %}

<!-- child.html -->
{% extends 'parent.html' %}
{% block category %}Books{% endblock category %}
```

for Arabic translation I need to use `blocktrans`, and I need to use different children names as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The docs of `blocktrans`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/translation/#std:templatetag-blocktrans) state the following:

> Other block tags (for example `{% for %}` or `{% if %}`) are not allowed inside a blocktrans tag.

`block` is another block tag, so it is not supported inside `blocktrans` either. The only thing allowed inside `blocktrans` is a direct variable substitution (without any filters, or attribute / method resolution using `.`).

In other words, what you're asking for is simply not possible with `blocktrans`. You'll have to reorganize your templates accordingly.

Comment: Ehm... This actually was my question. I know that it's not allowed, I wrote it this way to represent idea of what I am trying to do. Is there any work around for this?

Comment: No, as I wrote above, you'll have to reorganize your templates. Think of `blocktrans` as pretty much simple calls to `ugettext` with placeholders for variables. No dynamic features supported. What do you expect your PO files to look like if what you are asking for were possible?

Comment: Right :) Thank you very much. I'll better replace this translate function into python code and use ugettext then. Thank you again